# Font color on hover for list items in a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a combobox that has custom drawn items. It also makes use of zebra striping and because of this, the hover color is sometimes off. How can I control how it looks on hover?

Here's the code I use:

```
   Color zeros = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200);
    Color ones = Color.FromArgb(225, 225, 255);
    private void innerBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
        Pen pen = new Pen(e.ForeColor);


        if (e.Index % 2 == 0) {
            Brush backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(zeros);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, e.Bounds);
        } else {
            Brush backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(ones);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, e.Bounds);
        }

        Tenant tenant = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index] as Tenant;

        Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;

        //Draw Tenant Name
        if (tenant.TenantName != null) {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tenant.TenantName, e.Font, brush, rect, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        }
        rect.X += MaxTenantLength;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(rect.X - 3, rect.Y), new Point(rect.X - 3, rect.Y + e.Bounds.Height));

        //Draw Property
        if (tenant.Property != null) {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tenant.Property.PropertyName, e.Font, brush, rect, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        }
        rect.X += MaxPropertyLength;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(rect.X - 3, rect.Y), new Point(rect.X - 3, rect.Y + e.Bounds.Height));

        //Draw Rental Unit
        if (tenant.RenatlUnit != null) {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(tenant.RenatlUnit.UnitNumber, e.Font, brush, rect, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        }
        rect.X += MaxRentalUnitLength;

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the MouseMove event and create some kind of member variable to act as a flag if the mouse is over a striped "zebra" item. Call the Refresh() method, if necessary.